# JQuery | How to display variables when associated checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, checkbox

I'm creating a website that grabs weather information based on the location entered by the user. At the moment there are some features on the page with no functionality, it is still a work in progress. I apologies for the sloppy code.

I have 9 checkboxes at the top of my form that have the info that should be displayed and I'm not sure of the best method to edit the output accordingly.

In my JS file there is a block that grabs all of the relevant weather data and assigns it to variables. These variables are then used to generate a `<p>` element containing all of this info. How can I edit it to only display the variables that are selected via checkboxes?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inputType = 1;

  $("#Radio1").click(function() {
    $("#lbl1").text("City Name:");
    $("#lbl2").text("Country Code:");
    $("#Firstbox").removeAttr("min max step");
    $("#Secondbox").removeAttr("min max step");
    document.getElementById('Firstbox').value = '';
    document.getElementById('Secondbox').value = '';


    $("#Firstbox").attr({
      "type": "text",
      "pattern": "[a-zA-Z]{2,}",
      "placeholder": "Regina"
    });

    $("#Secondbox").attr({
      "type": "text",
      "pattern": "[a-zA-Z]{2}",
      "placeholder": "ca"
    });

    inputType = 1;
  });

  $("#Radio2").click(function() {
    $("#lbl1").text("Postal Code:");
    $("#lbl2").text("Country Code:");
    $("#Firstbox").removeAttr("min max step");
    $("#Secondbox").removeAttr("min max step");
    document.getElementById('Firstbox').value = '';
    document.getElementById('Secondbox').value = '';

    $("#Firstbox").attr({
      "type": "text",
      "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]",
      "placeholder": "S4X"
    });

    $("#Secondbox").attr({
      "type": "text",
      "pattern": "[a-zA-Z]{2}",
      "placeholder": "ca"
    });

    inputType = 2;
  });

  $("#Radio3").click(function() {
    $("#lbl1").text("Latitude:");
    $("#lbl2").text("Longitude:");
    $("#Firstbox").removeAttr("pattern");
    $("#Secondbox").removeAttr("pattern");
    document.getElementById('Firstbox').value = '';
    document.getElementById('Secondbox').value = '';

    $("#Firstbox").attr({
      "type": "number",
      "min": "-90",
      "max": "90",
      "step": "any",
      "placeholder": "50.4"
    });

    $("#Secondbox").attr({
      "type": "number",
      "min": "-180",
      "max": "180",
      "step": "any",
      "placeholder": "-105.5"
    });

    inputType = 3;
  });

  $("#SearchButton").click(function() {
    if (checkValidity()) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var SearchResponse = this.responseText;

          var obj = JSON.parse(SearchResponse);
          var city_name = obj["name"];
          var country_name = obj["sys"]["country"];
          var longitude = obj["coord"]["lon"];
          var latitude = obj["coord"]["lat"];
          var weather_description = obj["weather"][0]["description"];
          var temp = obj["main"]["temp"] - 273.15;
          var pressure = obj["main"]["pressure"];
          var humidity = obj["main"]["humidity"];
          var wind_speed = obj["wind"]["speed"];
          var wind_direction = obj["wind"]["deg"];
          var sunrise = new Date(obj["sys"]["sunrise"] * 1000);
          var sunset = new Date(obj["sys"]["sunset"] * 1000);

          var SearchResultsHTML = "City: " + city_name + "<br />" +
            "Country: " + country_name + "<br />" +
            "Longitude: " + longitude + "<br />" +
            "Latitude: " + latitude + "<br />" +
            "Weather: " + weather_description + "<br />" +
            "Temperature: " + temp + "<br />" +
            "Pressure: " + pressure + "<br />" +
            "Humidity: " + humidity + "<br />" +
            "Wind Speed: " + wind_speed + "<br />" +
            "Wind Direction: " + wind_direction + "<br />" +
            "Sunrise: " + sunrise.toLocaleTimeString() + "<br />" +
            "Sunset: " + sunset.toLocaleTimeString() + "<br />";

          $("#SearchResults").html(SearchResultsHTML);
        }
      }



      var Firstbox = $("#Firstbox").val();
      var Secondbox = $("#Secondbox").val();

      var apiKey = "52453f34dee0d65b1a41a02656142c6b";

      if (inputType == 1) {
        var SearchString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" +
          "?q=" + Firstbox + "," + Secondbox +
          "&APPID=" + apiKey;
      } else if (inputType == 2) {
        var SearchString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" +
          "?zip=" + Firstbox + "," + Secondbox +
          "&APPID=" + apiKey;
      } else if (inputType == 3) {
        var SearchString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" +
          "?lat=" + Firstbox + "&lon=" + Secondbox +
          "&APPID=" + apiKey;
      }

      xhttp.open("GET", SearchString, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
  });

  function displayError() {
    var first = document.getElementById('Firstbox');
    var second = document.getElementById('Secondbox');

    if (first.validity.valid) {
      if (inputType == 1 || inputType == 2) {
        alert("Country code must be 2 characters in length.");
      } else {
        alert("Longitude must be between -180 and 180");
      }
    } else {
      if (inputType == 1) {
        alert("City name must be longer than 1 character.");
      } else if (inputType == 2) {
        alert("Postal code must be 3 characters in length, following the format 'S4X'");
      } else {
        alert("Latitude must be between -90 and 90");
      }
    }
  }

  function checkValidity() {
    var first = document.getElementById('Firstbox');
    var second = document.getElementById('Secondbox');

    if (first.validity.valid && second.validity.valid) {
      return true;
    } else {
      displayError();
      return false;
    }
  }

  function checksSelected() {

  }
});
```

```css
.validated:valid {
  background-color: #BDF0A8;
}

.validated:invalid {
  background-color: #FAC3C9;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ticksel {
  border: solid black 1px;
}

tr,
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Final Project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weather.css">

<form id="searchForm" method="POST" action="URL">
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <h2>OpenWeatherMap Weather Search</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4>Search by:</h4>
      <input id="Radio1" name="searchBy" type="radio" checked /> City Name<br/>
      <input id="Radio2" name="searchBy" type="radio"> Postal Code<br/>
      <input id="Radio3" name="searchBy" type="radio" /> Latitude / Longitude<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4>Show in search results:</h4>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="" value=""> Longitude</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="" value=""> Latitude</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="" value=""> Temperature</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="" value=""> Pressure</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="" value=""> Humidity</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="" value=""> Wind Speed</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="" value=""> Wind Direction</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="" value=""> Sunrise</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="" value=""> Sunset</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <label id="lbl1">City Name:</label><input id="Firstbox" class="validated" type="text" required pattern=".{2,}" placeholder="Regina" />
    <label id="lbl2">Country Code:</label><input id="Secondbox" class="validated" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}" placeholder="ca" />
    <input id="SearchButton" type="button" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>

<div class="row col-md-12">
  <h4>Current Weather</h4>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-12">
  <p id="SearchResults"></p>
</div>

<div class="row col-md-12">
  <table width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Longitude</th>
        <th>Latitude</th>
        <th>Weather</th>
        <th>Temperature</th>
        <th>Pressure</th>
        <th>Humidity</th>
        <th>Wind Speed</th>
        <th>Wind Direction</th>
        <th>Sunrise</th>
        <th>Sunst</th>
        <th><a class="deleteAll" href="#">Clear Log</a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I changed http to https for your api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that will take the checked boxes and show their corresponding values

I changed your xmlhttp to getJSON

You can do

```
    let SearchResultsHTML = []
    SearchResultsHTML.push("City: " + city_name);
    SearchResultsHTML.push("Country: " + country_name);
    SearchResultsHTML.push("Weather: " + weather_description);
    if ($("#long").is(":checked")) SearchResultsHTML.push("Longitude: " + longitude);
    if ($("#lat").is(":checked")) SearchResultsHTML.push("Latitude: " + latitude);
    if ($("#temp").is(":checked")) SearchResultsHTML.push("Temperature: " + temp);
    if ($("#pres").is(":checked")) SearchResultsHTML.push("Pressure: " + pressure);
    if ($("#hum").is(":checked")) SearchResultsHTML.push("Humidity: " + humidity);
    if ($("#ws").is(":checked")) SearchResultsHTML.push("Wind Speed: " + wind_speed);
    if ($("#wd").is(":checked")) SearchResultsHTML.push("Wind Direction: " + wind_direction);
    if ($("#sunup").is(":checked")) SearchResultsHTML.push("Sunrise: " + sunrise.toLocaleTimeString());
    if ($("#sundown").is(":checked")) SearchResultsHTML.push("Sunset: " + sunset.toLocaleTimeString());
    $("#SearchResults").html(SearchResultsHTML.join("<br/>"));
```

or more elegantly add a span and toggle this at show time or even after

```
    let SearchResultsHTML = []
    SearchResultsHTML.push("City: " + city_name);
    SearchResultsHTML.push("Country: " + country_name);
    SearchResultsHTML.push("Weather: " + weather_description);
    SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='longSpan'>Longitude: " + longitude + "</span>");
    SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='latSpan'>Latitude: " + latitude + "</span>");
    SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='tempSpan'>Temperature: " + temp + "</span>");
    SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='pressSpan'>Pressure: " + pressure + "</span>");
    SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='humSpan'>Humidity: " + humidity + "</span>");
    SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='wsSpan'>Wind Speed: " + wind_speed + "</span>");
    SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='wdSpan'>Wind Direction: " + wind_direction + "</span>");
    SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='sunupSpan'>Sunrise: " + sunrise.toLocaleTimeString + "</span>");
    SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='sundownSpan'>Sunset: " + sunset.toLocaleTimeString() + "</span>");
    $("#SearchResults").html(SearchResultsHTML.join("<br/>"));
    showSpans();
  })
}
```

using

```
$(".ticksel").on("change", showSpans);
function showSpans() {
  $(".ticksel input").each(function() {
    const id = this.id;
    const checked = this.checked;
    if (id) {
      const $span = $("#" + id + "span");
      if ($span) $span.toggle(checked);
    }
  })
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inputType = 1;

  $("#Radio1").click(function() {
    $("#lbl1").text("City Name:");
    $("#lbl2").text("Country Code:");
    $("#Firstbox").removeAttr("min max step");
    $("#Secondbox").removeAttr("min max step");
    document.getElementById('Firstbox').value = '';
    document.getElementById('Secondbox').value = '';


    $("#Firstbox").attr({
      "type": "text",
      "pattern": "[a-zA-Z]{2,}",
      "placeholder": "Regina"
    });

    $("#Secondbox").attr({
      "type": "text",
      "pattern": "[a-zA-Z]{2}",
      "placeholder": "ca"
    });

    inputType = 1;
  });

  $("#Radio2").click(function() {
    $("#lbl1").text("Postal Code:");
    $("#lbl2").text("Country Code:");
    $("#Firstbox").removeAttr("min max step");
    $("#Secondbox").removeAttr("min max step");
    document.getElementById('Firstbox').value = '';
    document.getElementById('Secondbox').value = '';

    $("#Firstbox").attr({
      "type": "text",
      "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]",
      "placeholder": "S4X"
    });

    $("#Secondbox").attr({
      "type": "text",
      "pattern": "[a-zA-Z]{2}",
      "placeholder": "ca"
    });

    inputType = 2;
  });

  $("#Radio3").click(function() {
    $("#lbl1").text("Latitude:");
    $("#lbl2").text("Longitude:");
    $("#Firstbox").removeAttr("pattern");
    $("#Secondbox").removeAttr("pattern");
    document.getElementById('Firstbox').value = '';
    document.getElementById('Secondbox').value = '';

    $("#Firstbox").attr({
      "type": "number",
      "min": "-90",
      "max": "90",
      "step": "any",
      "placeholder": "50.4"
    });

    $("#Secondbox").attr({
      "type": "number",
      "min": "-180",
      "max": "180",
      "step": "any",
      "placeholder": "-105.5"
    });

    inputType = 3;
  });

  $("#SearchButton").click(function() {
    if (checkValidity()) {


      var Firstbox = $("#Firstbox").val();
      var Secondbox = $("#Secondbox").val();

      var apiKey = "52453f34dee0d65b1a41a02656142c6b";

      if (inputType == 1) {
        var SearchString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" +
          "?q=" + Firstbox + "," + Secondbox +
          "&APPID=" + apiKey;
      } else if (inputType == 2) {
        var SearchString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" +
          "?zip=" + Firstbox + "," + Secondbox +
          "&APPID=" + apiKey;
      } else if (inputType == 3) {
        var SearchString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" +
          "?lat=" + Firstbox + "&lon=" + Secondbox +
          "&APPID=" + apiKey;
      }


      $.getJSON(SearchString, function(obj) {
        var city_name = obj["name"];
        var country_name = obj["sys"]["country"];
        var longitude = obj["coord"]["lon"];
        var latitude = obj["coord"]["lat"];
        var weather_description = obj["weather"][0]["description"];
        var temp = obj["main"]["temp"] - 273.15;
        var pressure = obj["main"]["pressure"];
        var humidity = obj["main"]["humidity"];
        var wind_speed = obj["wind"]["speed"];
        var wind_direction = obj["wind"]["deg"];
        var sunrise = new Date(obj["sys"]["sunrise"] * 1000);
        var sunset = new Date(obj["sys"]["sunset"] * 1000);

        let SearchResultsHTML = []
        SearchResultsHTML.push("City: " + city_name);
        SearchResultsHTML.push("Country: " + country_name);
        SearchResultsHTML.push("Weather: " + weather_description);
        SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='longSpan'>Longitude: " + longitude + "</span>");
        SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='latSpan'>Latitude: " + latitude + "</span>");
        SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='tempSpan'>Temperature: " + temp + "</span>");
        SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='pressSpan'>Pressure: " + pressure + "</span>");
        SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='humSpan'>Humidity: " + humidity + "</span>");
        SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='wsSpan'>Wind Speed: " + wind_speed + "</span>");
        SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='wdSpan'>Wind Direction: " + wind_direction + "</span>");
        SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='sunupSpan'>Sunrise: " + sunrise.toLocaleTimeString + "</span>");
        SearchResultsHTML.push("<span id='sundownSpan'>Sunset: " + sunset.toLocaleTimeString() + "</span>");
        $("#SearchResults").html(SearchResultsHTML.join("<br/>"));
        showSpans();
      })
    }



  });

  $(".ticksel").on("change", showSpans);

  function showSpans() {
    $(".ticksel input").each(function() {
      const id = this.id;
      const checked = this.checked;
      if (id) {
        const $span = $("#" + id + "span");
        if ($span) $span.toggle(checked);
      }
    })
  }

  function displayError() {
    var first = document.getElementById('Firstbox');
    var second = document.getElementById('Secondbox');

    if (first.validity.valid) {
      if (inputType == 1 || inputType == 2) {
        alert("Country code must be 2 characters in length.");
      } else {
        alert("Longitude must be between -180 and 180");
      }
    } else {
      if (inputType == 1) {
        alert("City name must be longer than 1 character.");
      } else if (inputType == 2) {
        alert("Postal code must be 3 characters in length, following the format 'S4X'");
      } else {
        alert("Latitude must be between -90 and 90");
      }
    }
  }

  function checkValidity() {
    var first = document.getElementById('Firstbox');
    var second = document.getElementById('Secondbox');

    if (first.validity.valid && second.validity.valid) {
      return true;
    } else {
      displayError();
      return false;
    }
  }

  function checksSelected() {

  }
});
```

```css
.validated:valid {
  background-color: #BDF0A8;
}

.validated:invalid {
  background-color: #FAC3C9;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ticksel {
  border: solid black 1px;
}

tr,
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Final Project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weather.css">

<form id="searchForm" method="POST" action="URL">
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <h2>OpenWeatherMap Weather Search</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4>Search by:</h4>
      <input id="Radio1" name="searchBy" type="radio" checked /> City Name<br/>
      <input id="Radio2" name="searchBy" type="radio"> Postal Code<br/>
      <input id="Radio3" name="searchBy" type="radio" /> Latitude / Longitude<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4>Show in search results:</h4>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="long" value="yes"> Longitude</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="lat" value=""> Latitude</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="temp" value=""> Temperature</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="press" value=""> Pressure</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="hum" value=""> Humidity</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="ws" value=""> Wind Speed</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="wd" value=""> Wind Direction</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="sunup" value=""> Sunrise</div>
        <div class="col ticksel"><input type="checkbox" checked id="sundown" value=""> Sunset</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <label id="lbl1">City Name:</label><input id="Firstbox" class="validated" type="text" required pattern=".{2,}" placeholder="Regina" />
    <label id="lbl2">Country Code:</label><input id="Secondbox" class="validated" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}" placeholder="ca" />
    <input id="SearchButton" type="button" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>

<div class="row col-md-12">
  <h4>Current Weather</h4>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-12">
  <p id="SearchResults"></p>
</div>

<div class="row col-md-12">
  <table width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Longitude</th>
        <th>Latitude</th>
        <th>Weather</th>
        <th>Temperature</th>
        <th>Pressure</th>
        <th>Humidity</th>
        <th>Wind Speed</th>
        <th>Wind Direction</th>
        <th>Sunrise</th>
        <th>Sunst</th>
        <th><a class="deleteAll" href="#">Clear Log</a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see update. Much nicer since the users can change their minds and still see the values